# Registered coupon does not display in report filter

Tags: filter, report, magento-1.9, rules, coupon

I'm having a hard time generating coupon report used in Magento 1.9 accessing Reports -> Sales -> Coupons, I select a date period, order status I keep "any", **empty lines = "no"** and in Promotion rules, I **select = "specified"** then my problem happens, not all existing coupons are listed.

To try to solve this problem I tried to update the statistics, accessing Reports -> update statistics but without success, it gives the impression that it does not update. checking the **app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Block/Adminhtml/Report/Filter/Form/Coupon.php** file I found the code:

```
$rulesList = Mage::getResourceModel('salesrule/report_rule')->getUniqRulesNamesList();
```

which seems to me to bring the coupons in the filter of this report, but not all that are registered.

Even when registering a new coupon, it does not appear in the report's filter.

Has anyone been through this or has a way forward?

Answer (score 0):

[SORTED OUT]

I found that inside my mule there was a line that erased the coupon before placing the order at checkout. I changed the line to clear the coupon after finalizing the order and now everything is working.

This is the line:

```
$this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->setCouponCode('');
```